# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_forecast'

Tags: statistics, time-series, regression, forecasting, arima

### Can you please help me solve this, i don't know why I get this error: It's either I get this error or the forecasts are empty

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 34
     31     results = mod.fit()
     33     # Get forecast and confidence intervals
---> 34 forecast_monthly = results.get_forecast(steps=24)
     35 forecast_values.extend(forecast_monthly.predicted_mean)
     37     # Plot confidence intervals

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_forecast'
```

This is the part of the code:
`

```
for df, name in zip(dataframes, names):
    df_monthly = df['Close*'].resample('M').mean()[:-24]

    for series, period in [(df_monthly, 'Monthly')]:
        series = series.dropna()
        series = series.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()
        
        # Perform ADF test for stationarity
        result = adfuller(series)
        
        if result[1] >= 0.05:
            # If not stationary, difference the series
            series_diff = series.diff().dropna()
            
            # Initialize an empty list to store forecast values dynamically
            forecast_values = []
            conf_int_values = []
            
            # Implement a rolling window of fixed size (e.g., 24 months)
            window_size = 96
            for i in range(window_size, len(series_diff)):
                train_data = series_diff.iloc[i-window_size:i]
                mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(train_data, order=(0, 0, 0))
                results = mod.fit()

                # Get forecast and confidence intervals
            forecast_monthly = results.get_forecast(steps=24)
            forecast_values.extend(forecast_monthly.predicted_mean)
    
                # Plot confidence intervals
            conf_int = forecast_monthly.conf_int()
            conf_int_values.extend(conf_int)
```

I tried different indenting and multiple approaches